# Breakable table row in HTML

Tags: css, html-table, media-queries

Is there a way to make a table row breakable at a certain cell?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Some title descriptive text</td>
<td>nnumbers</td><td>Short text</td><td>datetime</td>
<tr>
... more rows
</table>
```

Now I would like this row to break after the first cell if the width of the viewport is too small (typically when used on mobile phones).

Is that achievable anyhow using html5 css3 and eventually some Javascript?

Comment: You mean for the second/third/fourth `td` elements to flow under the first? If it's for display purposes only (and not tabular data), you'd probably be better off with floated `div`s.

Comment: [`display: inline-block`](http://jsfiddle.net/nDc5v/2/) on the `td` elements for the table could work, although I suspect you're really just changing the `table td`s into a regular `div`-like element on display.

Comment: I would be *incredibly* confused by a table with broken rows.

Comment: That's why it's important that the break is controlled. If the table is poperly designed (first row width equals added widths of other cells + zebra colored table) it would be verry obvious that two consecutive rows present data about one (first) entity.

Comment: I considered using divs instead but i am actually dealing with tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of CSS2.1, it is possible by using appropriate `display` CSS attribute values. See this demo page:

http://dabblet.com/result/gist/1576044

...and the source:

http://dabblet.com/gist/1576044

Tested on a Galaxy Nexus phone, works, and should work for most Webkit-based mobile browsers. Also, it should work on Firefox Mobile and Opera, though I didn't test.

Long story short, use a media query to detect page width and set a `max-width` breakpoint and apply:

`css
table, tbody, thead, tr, td, th { display: block }`

Answer (score 1):

No. Table rows cannot be broken onto multiple lines. That'd imply you want TWO rows of cells instead of a single.

Comment: You [could](http://jsfiddle.net/nDc5v/1/), but it seems to defeat the purpose of using a table to begin with (note, not sure of cross-browser compatibility of that demonstration...).

Comment: The `tr td:eq(0)` [wasn't necessary](http://jsfiddle.net/nDc5v/2/). (Or at least I was using the wrong [pseudo-selector](http://jsfiddle.net/nDc5v/3/).)

Answer (score 1):

I needed something just like this for a project of mine; i needed to support old browsers so it doesn't use HTML5, just javascript to check the overall width/amount of rows able to handle:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=umFWx3mK *(Just copy it inside an HTML file and open it with a browser)*

```
$(window).resize(distribute)
$(document).ready(function(){

    allboxes = $(".box");
    $('#container').delegate(".box","mouseenter",function(){
        $(this).addClass('current') 
    }).delegate(".box","mouseleave",function(){
        $(this).removeClass('current')  
    });
    table = $("#table");
    distribute();

})

var lastfit, allboxes, table

function distribute(){
    var fitAmount = Math.floor($("#container").width()/180);


    if(lastfit!=fitAmount){
        if(fitAmount<1){fitAmount=1}
        lastfit = fitAmount;
        var clones = allboxes.clone(),
            emptycells = "", emptyrows = "", 
            trs = table.find("tr");

        for(var i=0;i<fitAmount;i++){
            emptycells += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }   

        trs.html(emptycells)

        var count = trs.length*fitAmount

        if(count < allboxes.length){
            var newRows = Math.ceil((allboxes.length - count)/fitAmount);
            for(var j=0;j<newRows;j++){
                emptyrows += "<tr>"+emptycells+"</tr>";
            }
        }       

        table.append(emptyrows)
        var tds = table.find("td"), trs = table.find("tr");

        clones.each(function(index){
            tds.eq(index).html("").append($(this))
        })
        allboxes = $(".box");

        trs.filter(function(){ return !/box/gi.test(this.innerHTML) }).remove()


    }
}

function boxmouseover(box){
    $(box).css("background","red")
}

function boxmouseout(box){
    $(box).css("background","#CCC")
}
```

Comment: Quote: "just javascript to check the overall width/amount of rows able to handle" and a link to the script; that is an answer.

Comment: Put it in the answer itself (just the relevant code and css). You can also http://jsfiddle.net a live example. (And no, your quote is not a complete answer, it's a comment. And see my comments under Mark B's answer.)

Comment: Is that is the case you should mark this answer as the correct one.